# add every Nth character to string

Tags: java, string, find, character

The task is to get every nth character and put it in a string.
I got this problem halfway solved.

If Miracle is the string typed in and the int = 2, i will get the following output: "Mrc", while it should be "Mrce".

Why is it missing out on the last character? The logic part seems reasonable to me.

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
  String firstletter = str.substring(0,1); // We store the first letter as well.
  String secondhalf = "";
  while(str.length() > n) { // Run as long as n reaches the end of the string.
    secondhalf += str.substring(n, n+1); // Add Nth character to string.
    n+=n;
  }
  return firstletter+secondhalf;
}
```

EDIT: Added a separate counter, int counter = n; so it doesnt double the value all the time.

Comment: Besides the 'n += n' bug, your implementation has horrible performance.

Comment: If you would like an easier way to extract single characters from a string by index, you could use 'str.charAt(index)' rather than substring.

Comment: @dzidzitop, im new to programming. Just trying to do some simple tasks. What would your solution be to maximize performance?

Comment: use StringBuffer and String#charAt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here:

```
n+=n;
```

first time it 2, then 4, then 8...

Just use separate counter.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I added a separate counter now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use charAt function in a for to do it:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
  String result="";
  for(i=0; i<str.length(); i=i+n){
    result+=str.charAt(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```